# I got error ssh: connect to host SOME_HOST port 22: Connection refused on CentOS 5.6 after running Yum update

Tags: centos, ssh

Let me briefly tell what I did. 
I have a HOST_NAME running on CentOS 5.6.
Today I've connected to it via SSH and run `yum update`, after some time, my SSH connection frozen. 
Then I've tried to reconnect to it and all what I get is:
`ssh: connect to host SOME_HOST port 22: Connection refused`
Server is running, only problem that we can't access it.
Please help me what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if port 22 is open. You can do it with `nmap HOST_NAME` from your workstation.
However,

> Connection refused

tells you it is closed.

If port is closed and you have no physical access to the server, there isn't much you can do. Ask someone who has access to check if `sshd` is running and to check the firewall.

Comment: OK Thanks for your reply. As you said I've executed `nmap`on it, it has shown me that it is closed. Then I've runned through PHP `ps ax` and didn't find `sshd`. Now I need to go to data-center resolve this issue. What should I do when I will have phys.access to server? Thanks

Comment: If you have PHP-shell, you can check everything remotely. Anyway, commands gonna be the same on the phys. console. Firstly, make sure `sshd` is installed: `yum list installed openssh-server`. If so, make sure it is running: `service sshd status`, if it's not running - `sudo service sshd start`. Also make `chkconfig sshd on` to have SSH daemon running across reboots. If it is running and listening port 22 (`netstat -atnl`), it maybe the firewall who doesn't let packets reach port 22. Then check `iptables` rules.

Comment: Man you just saved my life. I did everything that you said, the problem was that `yum update` command got frozen and `sshd` turned off. I've just killed `yum update process` and started `sshd` service again. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Nice to hear it! Welcome!